# in jQuery is there a ways to loop over an array such that before it loops to the next loop it first waits for the responce from the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, loops

Let me explain my situation,

I have a list of checkboxes in a fieldset, for each checkbox i would like to send a jquery get and wait for the response from the server which can be random time 10 seconds to a long time once i get the result display the result and continue to the next loop.

```
        $(function() {
            $("button[name=distributeGroupProgramsToCustomersNow]").click(function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("button[name=distributeGroupProgramsToCustomersNow]").attr("disabled", "");
                $("input[name='distributeGroups-GroupsList']:checked").each(function ()
                {
                    // the loop that waits for the response 
                });
                $("button[name=distributeGroupProgramsToCustomersNow]").removeAttr("disabled", "");
            });
        });
```

How do i achieve this in jQuery?

Any help is greatly appriciated, Thanks!

Comment: You should be using [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr` to change the `disabled` property. Additionally, you can save both cycles and space by caching your button selector: `$btn = $("button[name=distributeGroupProgramsToCustomersNow]");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by making the call to your ajax synchronous, that way the loop has to wait for the response before it can continue.

```
$.each(arrayOfItems, function(i,v){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/my/file.extension',
    type: 'GET', //this is already the default, only placed as an example.
    async: false, // this is what you want to make sure things 'wait'.
    data: 'checkedValue='+v, //value of our item.
    success: function(data){
      //manipulate / insert the data where you need.
      $("#someElement").append(data);       
    }
  });
});
```

**How it works**

For each item, we have an ajax call. Disabling 'asynchronous' ajax forces the server to 'wait' on the *previous* AJAX request to be completed before processing the *next* AJAX request. This replicates the behavior that you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function that calls itself

```
 var ajaxLoopInput = $("input[name='distributeGroups-GroupsList']:checked");
 var i = 0;

 ajaxIt(i);

 function ajaxIt(index){         
     if(i < ajaxLoopInput.length){ 
         ajaxLoopInput.eq(index).dosomething(); //if you need the current item in list.
         $.ajax({
              //your ajax stuff
              success : function(){
                  i++;
                  ajaxIt(i);
              }
         });
     }else{
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this without blocking and using synchronous calls, is to use the array as a queue, and have a function that pulls the first item from the queue, runs the query, and then calls itself.

```
var myQueueArray = [1, 2, 3];
var currentIndex = 0;

function queueGet() {
    if(currentIndex >= myQueueArray.length) {
        return;
    }

    $.get("/my/url/", { 'checkedValue', myQueueArray[currentIndex] }, function(data) {
        //this is the important part...call the queue again until it's done
        currentIndex += 1;
        queueGet();
    });
}
```

The version above is non-destructive of the array. You could of course just pop the array too.